# Does dynamic quorum/witness re-adjust the quorum majority figure?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, clustering

Example:
[image]

Quorum majority should be floor((5/2)+1) = 3. Meaning 3 must be active for cluster to be remain active.

My question is - does dynamic quorum/witness ever result in readjustment of the above value? For example - say 2 nodes go down, so we have 2 nodes and 1 file share remaining.

At this point, is the quorum majority (number of nodes needed for cluster survival) re-calculated based on the remaining - that is - floor(3/2)+1 = 2 or should the majority still be 3 (which means cluster goes down upon failure of a node or file share)?

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic quorum handles the node vote assignment, well, dynamically. If the nodes do not fail all at once, it allows the cluster to survive even on its last working member.

In the example scenario, the cluster would survive the two servers failing, even simultaneously - you'd have 5 votes initially, lose 2 and you still have 3 available, which can sustain the quorum.

There's a handy table with multiple scenarios that can help you predict the cluster behavior here: [Cluster quorum overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/hci/concepts/quorum#cluster-quorum-overview).

In this same page, there's a line that reads:

> The total number of votes required for quorum is now determined based on the number of nodes available.

So, according to the official literature, the quorum majority will be recalculated based on the remaining available nodes.

Caveat: you'll see a couple of 50/50 in that table - this is because not all the nodes have a vote, and if the majority of voting nodes fails, the cluster can fail even with a dynamic quorum.

Comment: After 2 nodes fail, `At this point, is the quorum majority (number of nodes needed for cluster survival) re-calculated based on the remaining - that is - floor(3/2)+1 = 2 or should the majority still be 3 (which means cluster goes down upon failure of a node or file share)?`

Comment: Just updated the answer explicitly stating that yes, the required majority will be recalculated based on the amount of available votes.